# Redirect to ReturnUrl after successful cookie authentication in Owin, Katana & Nancy

Tags: c#, authentication, owin, nancy, katana

I am using Owin, Katana and Nancy to host a simple site with an authentication required section.
Note I am also using nuget package - **Nancy.MSOwinSecurity**

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = Constants.AuthenticationType,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/Login"),
});
app.UseNancy();
```

Here is my module code

```
public class LoginModule : NancyModule
{
    public LoginModule()
    {
        Post["login"] = p =>
        {
            var name = Request.Form.name;
            var auth = Context.GetAuthenticationManager();
            var claims = new List<Claim> {new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name)};
            var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Constants.AuthenticationType);
            auth.SignIn(id);
            // redirect how????
            return View["index"];
        };
    }
}
```

My submitting form

```
<form name="login" action="/login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <ul>
        ...
    </ul>
</form>
```

Now I am looking to redirect after successful login to the ReturnUrl -

e.g. Login?ReturnUrl=%2Fblah%2blahblah

There seems to be no redirect method like in forms authentication plus the query string parameters property is empty.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried `Response.AsRedirect("/");` or `GetRedirect("/");` on `NancyContext`

Using your code sample:

```
public class LoginModule : NancyModule
{
    public LoginModule()
    {
        Post["login"] = p =>
        {
            var name = Request.Form.name;
            var auth = Context.GetAuthenticationManager();
            var claims = new List<Claim> {new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, name)};
            var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Constants.AuthenticationType);

            auth.SignIn(id);

            return Response.AsRedirect(p.Request.Query.RedirectUrl);
        };
     }
}
```

Comment: I can do Response.Redirect but I can't get the redirect url. GetRedireect and p.RediretUrl don't exist.

Comment: Updated - I used the route parameter accessor, not the query string accessor. As a side note `Context.GetRedirect(p.Request.Query.RedirectUrl)` is the GetRedirect way to approach this.

Comment: Could you update the code sample with the correct code please.