# Creating Redirect URI for OAuth2 in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, oauth-2.0

I have Asp.Net MVC application and Xamarin.Forms mobile application with Azure Mobile App as back end. All will be hosted in Azure cloud. I need to integrate Google, Microsoft and Azure AD authentication into it.

I came across many tutorials/blogs on how to do this, but none on how to create my own redirect URI.

I would like to create one universal redirect URI for each of the authentication provide and host it in cloud. Basically it should process the token, and I would like to retrieve basic user properties like user ID and name to be returned back to the calling app - in my case either the MVC or Xamarin mobile app.

Appreciate any sample project on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think following two urls should be able to give you good idea about how to use oauth in azure mobile:

http://www.strathweb.com/2014/02/running-owin-pipeline-new-net-azure-mobile-services/

http://blog.nankov.com/azure-mobile-services-configuring-the-owin-pipeline/

As per oauth itself. The you will need to understand (if you havent already) different oauth flow types and decide which one best suits your scenario.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749

For e.g. if you are using pure javascript client then **implicit grant** will be the best option in my view.

If you look at the implicit grant flow (for e.g.) it uses redirect uri. So When client makes a request , it uses a predefined url (given by the auth server to the client before hand). The server look at the url (and the client_id) and if it matches then it sends the response back (with a token) to that url only.

The url is location at the client's app would be something like  https://client.com/someuniquelocation/ (for e.g.)

Hope this helps.

Edit:

Have a look at the following:

[Redirect to ReturnUrl after successful cookie authentication in Owin, Katana & Nancy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23539987/redirect-to-returnurl-after-successful-cookie-authentication-in-owin-katana-n)

http://xabikos.com/web%20application/interception/middleware/2015/01/26/asp.net---create-an-owin-middleware-to-trigger-a-permanent-redirect.html

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.owinresponse.redirect(v=vs.113).aspx

Comment: does that means that I have options to use OAuth2 without redirection endpoint? I just don't specify it as long as its not registered? And I can still access the profile details?

Comment: In the implicit grant you have to use redirection when you request token. This is a fundamental security mechanism so that the token can only be sent to the rightful owner. When you request profile details you make a webapi request (for e.g.) and use the token in the request header. This way the resource can identify request is a valid one. Now at this point if you want to redirect the user to another site then you can do it on the client side.

Comment: So my question again, how can I create a redirection URI in ASP.Net?